# CS50 Speller handles most basic words properly

Tags: c, cs50

Hello everyone I am working on CS50's speller exercise and I came across this error.

> handles most basic words properly

The full error message is:

```
running ./speller basic/dict basic/text...
checking for output "MISSPELLED WORDS\n\n\nWORDS MISSPELLED: 0\nWORDS IN DICTIONARY: 8\nWORDS IN TEXT: 9\n"...

Expected Output:
MISSPELLED WORDS


WORDS MISSPELLED:     0
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  8
WORDS IN TEXT:        9
Actual Output:
MISSPELLED WORDS

over

WORDS MISSPELLED:     1
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  8
WORDS IN TEXT:        9
```

this is my check function:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dictionary.h"


// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;


// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 27;

int word_count;

char dictionary_word[LENGTH + 1];
// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    unsigned int word_pos = hash(word);

    node *cursor = table[word_pos];

    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if ((strcasecmp(cursor->word, word)) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

hash function:

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word) 
{ 
 int index = 0; 
 for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0' ; i++) 
 { 
   index += tolower(word[i]); 
 } 
 return index % N ; 
}
```

I would really appreciate some guidance, I am not a C expert so I would appreciate an in depth explanation because I am looking forward to learning as much as I can.

Thanks!

Comment: Check function looks ok to me. Could you add your hash function? And whenever you use pointers, initialize them first! Otherwise, you do not know where that pointer is pointing.. You may get segmentation fault..

Comment: here it is: unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int index = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0 ; word[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        index += tolower(word[i]) ;
    }
    return index % N ;
}

Comment: any pointer that is wrongfully initialized? @earik87

Comment: Can you place hash function to your question in the code snippet?

Comment: @earik87 added the hash function to the question.

Answer (score 0):

just changed the hash function and worked.

hash function:

```
// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int index = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0 ; word[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        index += tolower(word[i]) ;
    }
    return index % N ;
}
```

and also changed the value of N to: 65536